# Add a global hover effect with Vue Router

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to vue and I've done my best to figure this out, but I'm not sure what to try next.

Essentially, I'd like to change the cursor in my app from inactive to active on certain items — some are links and some are div elements. I've successfully done this in isolation on one route, but I'd like to apply the script so that all my routes are affected.

It's not a huge deal if I have to recreate this solution on every route, but I'd like to see if there's a more efficient way.

In my working example I'm using this method:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      hover: false,
      cursorActive: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleCursorHover(s) {
      this.hover = s;
      this.cursorActive = s;
    }
  }
}
```

and this in the template (inactiveCursor and activeCursor are the css classes that contain the cursor styles):

```
<main :class="{ inactiveCursor: !cursorActive, activeCursor: cursorActive }">
<div @mouseover="handleCursorHover(true)" @mouseleave="handleCursorHover(false)"></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

In methods You have use  this.cursorInactive is not exits in data so that please change **this.cursorInactive** to  **this.cursorActive**

```
methods: {
handleCursorHover(s) {
  this.hover = s;
  this.cursorActive = s;
}
```

}

I hope this work fine.

Comment: ah yes sorry that was a typo — it's correct in my code (so it's working for me), but thanks for pointing that out!